# Drag image inside a div cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm writing an email template builder. How can I drag image inside one of div cells ?
Actually I want to drag yellow and red divs to main container and then drag image inside one of div cells.

The HTML is:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:900px;height:400px; border:solid 1px red;">

    drag here

  </div>

 <h2>From this list</h2>
<div id="toolBox" class="linked">

<div class="customeDraggable">
    <div style="border: solid 1px yellow; float: right; height: 150px; width: 50%"> 1 </div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px yellow; float: left; height: 150px; width: 49%"> 2 </div>
</div>

<div class="customeDraggable">
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; float: right; height: 150px; width:     33%"> 1 </div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left; height: 150px; width: 33%"> 2 </div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left; height: 150px; width: 33%"> 3 </div>
</div>


<div class="customeDraggable">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artua/mac/128/Setting-icon.png" />
</div>


</div>
```

and the JavaScript code is:

```
$(function () {
toolBox = $('#toolBox'),
container = $('.container'),


container.sortable({
    revert: false,
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).data("lastItem", ui.item);
        debugger;
    },
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).data("lastItem").find('img').css('opacity', '1');
        debugger;
        //ui.item.draggable('destroy').css('opacity', '0.2');
    }
});



toolBox.find('.customeDraggable').draggable({
    connectToSortable: container,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: handleDragStop
});
function handleDragStop(event, ui) {
    debugger;
    var offsetXPos = parseInt(ui.offset.left);
    var offsetYPos = parseInt(ui.offset.top);
    //alert("Drag stopped!\n\nOffset: (" + offsetXPos + ", " + offsetYPos + ")\n");
}


});
```

Here is the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5025enr/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a sample , now just customize it . [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/j9c7s5aw/)

the html :

```
<ul class="widgets col-sm-2">
<li class="col-xs-6" data-type="grid-row" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/jetstrap-site/images/builder/components/grid_row.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;" data-html='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 target"><h3>Span 4</h3><p>Content</p></div><div class="col-md-4 target"><h3>Span 4</h3><p>Content</p></div><div class="col-md-4 target"><h3>Span 4</h3><p>Content</p></div></div>'><a href="#">Grid Row</a>
</li>
<li class="col-xs-6" data-type="button" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/jetstrap-site/images/builder/components/button.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;" data-html='<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Default</a>'><a href="#">Button</a>
</li>
<li class="col-xs-6" data-type="heading" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/jetstrap-site/images/builder/components/heading.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;" data-html='<h1>Heading 1</h1>'><a href="#">Heading</a>
</li>
<li class="col-xs-6" data-type="jumbotron" style="background-image:  url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/jetstrap-site/images/builder/components/hero_unit.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"  data-html='<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Jumbotron</h1>
<p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for   calling  extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
</div>'><a href="#">Jumbotron</a>
</li>
```

the css :

```
.widgets {
height: 800px;
background: #454443;
}
.widgets li {
float: left;
color: #fff;
list-style: none;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
opacity: 0.85;
width: 125px;
padding-top: 75px;
text-align: center;
font-family:'ProximaNova-Regular', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-      serif;
}
.widgets li:hover {
background-color: #454443;
opacity: 1.0;
cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.widgets li a:hover {
cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.widgets li a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: none;
}
.widget {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 15px;
}

.page {
  height: 800px;
border: thin solid red;
}

.page .row {
min-height: 50px;
}

.page .row div {
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 30px;
border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

and the js :

```
// Make all widgets draggable
$(".widgets li").draggable({
revert: "valid",
helper: "clone",
cursor: "move"
});



setDrop = function(targets) {
$(targets).droppable({
    accept: ".widgets li",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(this);
        var el = $($(ui.helper[0]).data("html"));
        $(this).append(el);
        setDrop($(".target", el));
    }
});
};
setDrop($('.target'));
```

BTW, jquery-UI.js , bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js are needed

Answer (score 0):

Once you have moved the yellow `div` to the red, you must change the class of the div, in order to be able to receive stuff by dragging, instead of just being an element.

On the other hand, if the image cannot be dragged into the red div, it just must to be able to be dragged into the yellow one with a new class just for that.

Comment: check this, is very generic, but is working for your case:
http://jsfiddle.net/v5025enr/4/

Comment: It works, but if I want to get that part html, the image is not there.

Comment: Check how I do with ui.item in the `beforeStop` in the beforeStop of the new droppable, you must get the element and save it in a variable or somewhere